# How to retain workspace segregation across display changes?

Tags: display, pantheon, gala

I am moving to Elementary from a bespoke desktop on Arch, using i3. My workflow consists of having multiple windows per project, and separating the projects by workspaces.

I use a ThinkPad T430s and a dock.

On Elementary Juno beta, when I open some windows and separate them into different workspaces, they stay where they should, regardless of closing the laptop, sleeping/suspending, et cetera.

If I dock the laptop and close the lid, disabling the laptop LVDS screen, all my windows are moved to a single workspace on my external VGA monitor.

This does not happen in reverse; making windows in workspaces while docked, then undocking and opening the laptop, I find all my windows where I left them.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it from happening?